# How to run old ubuntu distros with support for download packages?

Tags: ubuntu

My purpose is to run old services in virtualbox through old versions of ubuntu, but every time I try to install the package I need is impossible because there are no repositories, it's like they delete the repositories for old versions of ubuntu and I can't download what I need.

Is there any way to have a local repository with all the packages associated with an older version of ubuntu for my purpose?

Comment: If course it's possible. It's documented how to set up your own mirror. But that doesn't change the fact that you first need a source for the packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [old-releases.ubuntu.com](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/). There you'll find *all* releases, all the way back to [Warty Warthog](https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/warty/).

Unsupported releases are removed from the main repositories, as demand is reduced. It's permanently archived at old-releases.